# Having an issue exporting localhost database from phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am following along with this tutorial in order to upload a WordPress site I design on localhost, however when I try and export the database from phpmyadmin, it doesn't work. I do not get an error, but has been taking several hours and I think it keeps timing out? The site is quite large so not sure if this why (117Mib).

Any assistance is much appreciated or if anyone has another suggestion on how to get the site live? I have already tried the All-in-One-WP Migration plugin but it is too large.

Thanks, 
Summer

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WP Migrate DB** plugin and it will always work.

HERE: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Simply go to Tools > Migrate > Export

Even if DB is large it will still work.

Let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I have installed the plugin and exported my locahost database. How do I then import it to my new WordPress site on the active server? It is saying I need to purchase the pro version but is there a way to do this without purchasing anything or a plugin?

Comment: There are alternate options available to import.
1) Cpanel > Go to PhpMyAdmin > Import
2) Copy adminer.php and import. Ref: https://www.adminer.org/
3) IF SSH access then run command to import

Comment: Okay so i exported my site using WP Migrate DB. I downloaded the .sql file to my computer. I then got onto phpMyAdmin for my online hosting account, went to import but get an error.

Comment: Error
SQL query:


#
# Delete any existing table `wp_actionscheduler_actions`
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_actionscheduler_actions`
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or video on how you are trying to import??

Comment: The import has worked now, however when I go the URL nothing happens. This is the URL and where the new site should be for Everything Fabric: www.summerkatedesigns.com/everythingfabric/

Comment: Have you replaced the URL while exporting DB from WP Migrate DB plugin?
IF NO then that could be causing problem otherwise it's a matter of debugging.
Need to enable WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

use SQLyog(SQLyog is a GUI tool for the RDBMS MySQL.) for better database performance.
By this tool you can manage local database and server database easily.

Comment: Are you sure that this app will help? 117Mb is not like very huge dump so the problem is not this case

Comment: I am not wanting to purchase a new program, I am happy using MAMP and phpMyAdmin  however I will give it ago and download the free trial. If you could link any tutorials that would be appreciated.